# Parse non-ascii string from argv in 'main' function C++

Tags: c++, arguments, command-line-arguments, widechar

I am writing a console program that processes files passed by the user as launch arguments
(reads, processes in a certain way, writes to other files).
The problem is that file paths can contain chinese, german, ukrainian and other non-standard letters, which are incorrectly processed by the program (impossible to open files due to an incorrect path). I can use 'wmain' and 'wchar_t** argv' instead of 'main' and 'char** argv',
but I haven't seen any library for argument parsing that supports wchar_t argv, and I, besides paths, have to parse many more parameters of different types.

Tell me, please:

1. Is it possible to get by with exclusively ordinary char when processing paths containing non-ascii characters?
2. Do you know any argument parsing libraries that support 'wmain'? (most popular, 'argparse', [doesn`t support](https://github.com/p-ranav/argparse/issues/49) it.)

Comment: Regarding #1 you cannot do anything at all until you know what **encoding** your non-ASCII  characters are represented by. This crucial information is missing from the description above. Do you know the encoding?

Comment: Dou you mean replacements for `strcmp()`, `strlen()`, and such?  Don't `wcscmp()`, `wcslen()` and related (in `<wchar.h>`, or `<cwchar>` in C++) work for you?

Comment: @Paulo1205 no, I don't mean that. I described exactly what the problem is: I either can’t parse the rest of the arguments (since there is no parsing library that supports wmain), or I can’t get paths from argv if they contain non-ascii characters

Comment: It depends on your OS and compiler. With Windows and MSVC, you don't have a lot of choice but to use `wmain` and `wchar_t** argv`.

Comment: @Chase, if you cannot find a library, you can make your own with the building blocks I suggested.  
Also, you can probably get at least a little further with regular `char`-based libraries if you properly configure locale in your program, but YMMV.  
Finally, with a simple Google, I found about a version of `getopt` that was ported to Unicode (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/157001/Full-getopt-Port-for-Unicode-and-Multibyte-Microso)  Would that work for you?

Comment: `boost::program_options` support `wchar_t`. Googling "wchar_t getopt" returns quite a bit of results too.